# Embedding variable in HTML from another c# class

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I am using an ASP.NET framework. Within my welcome page (after a user logs in) I want to customize the paragraph text to include their login information. For example:

```
<p>
   Welcome to the website!
</p>
```

Is what the code would have currently, but what I want is:

```
<p>
       Welcome <var=Username> to the website!
</p>
```

Now obviously that is not correct, i didn't expect it to be. I just want to demonstrate what i am trying to do. I thought about using JavaScript to accomplish this somehow, but that seemed a bit overly complicated. My variable "Username" comes from another class in a .cs file elsewhere. How can I embed that variable into my `<p></p>` ?

Comment: Can you share the .cs file?

Comment: I don't see what that matters, its just a simple string variable located in a class named 'User'

Comment: it matters so we can try and provide with a more concise answer.  If you check my answer below it should help.

Comment: @Nibirue - because all of of answers we put = User  and assume you know how to get the User's name ,  if you were unable to get the Users name more code could be provided to help with that as well

Comment: In this case, yes. but i have already retrieved the correct username and saved it in the codebhind for the welcome page, so that is a non-issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a label in your markup:

```
<p>
       Welcome <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" /> to the website!
</p>
```

And then in the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblUsername.Text = "username";  // set to the username variable here
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, as well as the asp:Literal method; both have the same problem for me. No variable info shows up. I declare the lblUsername in code behind like this: protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblUsername; I suspect this is part of the problem.

Comment: @Nibirue Can you set a breakpoint here and see if your username variable is actually populated?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `<asp:Literal` in place of your marker then in the Page_Load set the value as required `ltUsername.Text = UserName;`

```
<p>Welcome <asp:Literal ID="ltUsername" runat="server" /> to the website</p>
```

and in your code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ltUsername.Text = Username; // whatever that may be
}
```

The literal outputs only what you supply - whereas an asp:Label will wrap your text in a `<span>` tag and adds extra mark-up which can be confusing. For that reason I only use `asp:Label` for actual `<label>` elements (those associated with an `input`).

Comment: Thanks for the post; whenever i try this, nothing appears in the space for the Literal. I do everything like you suggest, and declare the variable protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal ltUsername; like that, but still nothing shows up for the username.

Comment: No need to declare the "variable" in your code behind. It is instantiated by your server side markup.

Comment: As a test can you try setting the literal to `"Test"` then you should see the string Test show up where the literal is. If that works then you know it's populating the variable that needs looking into.

Answer (score 2):

if that variable comes from another class you will need a way to store it somehow. One way to do that is by putting it in a session.

so in your "other" class

```
Session["myVariable"] = variable;
```

Then in the page you want to set the "Welcome "Variable" to the website" you do the following:

first, create a property:

```
public string name {get;set;}
```

Then, in your page_load:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
          name = Session["myVariable"]
   }
```

then simply put the following code in your .aspx page:

```
 Hello <%= name %> , welcome to the website!
```

Alternatively you could also do:

Page_Load:

```
Label1.Text = Session["myVariable"].ToString();
```

.aspx:

```
Hello, <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /> welcome to the website.
```

Answer (score 1):

in Html

```
<p>
       Welcome <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server"></asp:Label> to the website!
</p>
```

then in .cs file in Page_Load

```
lblUserName.Text = {The User's First Name}
```

if you post more code on how you did the authentication , then I can replace `{The Users First Name}`  with actual code.  For now just use that on your own to put in FirstName Code

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a server side control, i.e. a Label, Textbox and do:

```
<asp:Label id="username" runat="server" />
```

The above party goes in your markup section.

Then on your `Page_Load` event or where the username property is located in the .cs file populated you can do:

```
  username.Text = User;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a tour through a tutorial site and get familiar with the syntax and structure.  A good place to start is here, http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp (Gosh I can imagine the feedback on this already ;) )

What you are trying to accomplish is very simple, you can also just install some of the Templates that come along with Visual Studio (if you have it) ... some do exactly what you are  trying to achieve.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that best way to go is using:

```
var page=HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
```

Than:

```
page.Header.Controls.Add(literalcontrol);
```

So can you use that from a class, and dont need to write it on each code behind.